# How to access the collider attached to the children of a prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I have attached a script to a prefab and the script is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class destroyer: MonoBehaviour {

    Circles circles;

    Collider2D collider1;
    Collider2D collider2;

    private void Start() {
        collider1 = gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent < Collider2D > ();
        collider2 = gameObject.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent < Collider2D > ();
        circles = FindObjectOfType < Circles > ();
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (transform.position.y < 2) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            circles.instantiator();

        }

    }
    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) {

        if (collider1.bounds.Contains(other.bounds.max) && collider1.bounds.Contains(other.bounds.min)) {
            print("2");
            if (other.bounds.Contains(collider2.bounds.max) && other.bounds.Contains(collider2.bounds.min)) {
                print("3");
                if (transform.position.y > 3) {
                    print("4");
                    Destroy(other.gameObject);
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                    circles.instantiator();
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

`OnTriggerStay2D` function is getting called but the condition when a GameObject is completely inside the collider 1 and outside the collider 2 is never true even if the other GameObject satisfies the condition.
Previously when I have attached both collider to the prefab then this condition becomes true when the game object satisfy the condition. But after the change it is not working. I think that I am not accessing the collider of a child properly or there is some other error. Please help me to resolve this problem.

[image]

This is the pic of gameobject with two children each having circular collider

[image]

and when other game object having circular collider comes in between both the circular collider then I want to perform some action.
this is ultimately what I want to achieve

Edit : the same function is working fine and I am getting what I want  when I put the prefab on the scene and then running the game . But it is not working with the same prefab which is instantiated after running the game.

Comment: I think you may create scripts next to your children colliders and separate your logic from each collider.

Comment: @loic.lopez you are saying to attach two different script to both the child and then perform the function? But I want to know that why this piece of code is not running even when the condition is true. How can I make it work ?

Comment: If I understand well the `print("3");` is not showing in the Unity console?

Comment: @loic.lopez print("2") is also not showing in the unity console

Comment: @MohammadAL-Haque the two colliders are enabled and active right?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `collider1.bounds.Contains(other.bounds.max) && collider1.bounds.Contains(other.bounds.min)`? If you want to know what collider is triggered I think is better to attach two differents scripts to both child so you can get rid of your two condition because you will know in the method `OnTriggerStay2D` of the `child1` that it is this object colliding with each other.

Comment: @loic.lopez yes of course they are enabled and active because then only OnTriggerStay2D is getting called I have checked it by writing print("1") just under the OnTriggerStay2D and it is printing it to the console

Comment: @loic.lopez there are two concentric circle and when a GameObject with a circular collider comes in between the two colliders of the concentric circle I want it to destroy.this is what I want to achieve . If nothing works then I will try  the solution suggested by you but before when both the collider are attached to the prefab then there was no problem.

Comment: Does `collider1` is your circle?

Comment: @loic.lopez yes collider 1 is a circle and collider 2 can be circle or square or a triangle depending on which prefab is instantiated . But collider 1 is always a circle

Comment: Does [Physics2D.OverlapCircle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) can help you?

Comment: You way also see: [Collider2D.IsTouching](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219206/discussion-between-mohammad-al-haque-and-loic-lopez).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can improve your conditions by using `Collider2D.IsTouching` like so:

```cs
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) {

    if (collider1.IsTouching(other)) {
        print("2");
        if (other.IsTouching(collider2)) {
            print("3");
            if (transform.position.y > 3) {
                print("4");
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
                Destroy(gameObject);
                circles.instantiator();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Reference: [ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html)**

> **Check whether this collider is touching the collider or not.**
> It is important to understand that checking whether colliders are touching or not is performed against the last physics system update; that is the state of touching colliders at that time. If you have just added a new Collider2D or have moved a Collider2D but a physics update has not yet taken place then the colliders will not be shown as touching. This function returns the same collision results as the physics collision or trigger callbacks.

**EDIT 1:**

You can also combine the previous code with: **[Physics2D.OverlapCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCollider.html)**

So you can do:

```cs
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) {

    if (collider1.IsTouching(other)) {
        Collider2D[] results;
        int elements = collider2.OverlapCollider(new ContactFilter2D, results);
        if (elements > 0) {
            // do some extra work with your result Collider2D array
            // here
            //
            if (transform.position.y > 3) {
                print("4");
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
                Destroy(gameObject);
                circles.instantiator();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In this case if the the other collider is touching both the collider 1 and 2 then the function is getting performed but I want the function to be performed when the other collider lies completely inside collider 1 and collider 2 lies completely inside the other collider.

Comment: So the collider `Collider2D other` must be inside both `Collider2D collider1` and `Collider2D collider2`?

Comment: Collider2D other  should be inside Collider2D collider 1 and the the Collider2D collider 2 should be completely inside Collider2D other.